# Play subproject can't import Play-json classes on IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.6

I've split my app into sub-projects for better organization, however. My core sub-module which is a play app can't import `play.api.libs.json.Json`
Here is my `build.sbt`

```
# project/Common.scala
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object Common {

  val settings = Seq(
    organization := "com.company.app",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.5"
  )

  val dependencies = new {

    val macwireVersion = "2.3.0"
    val reactiveMongoVersion = "0.13.0-play26"
    val slickVersion = "3.0.3"
    val postgresVersion = "42.2.2"
    val scalatestPlayVersion = "3.1.2"

    val macwire = "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "macros" % macwireVersion % "provided"
    val reactivemongo = "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % reactiveMongoVersion
    val slick = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % slickVersion
    val slickEvolutions = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % slickVersion
    val postgresql = "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % postgresVersion
    val scalatestPlay = "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % scalatestPlayVersion % Test
  }

  lazy val commonDependencies = Seq(
    dependencies.macwire,
    dependencies.reactivemongo,
    dependencies.slick,
    dependencies.slickEvolutions,
    dependencies.postgresql,
    dependencies.scalatestPlay
  )
}


# build.sbt
lazy val core = (project in file("modules/core"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(
    name := "app-core",
    libraryDependencies ++= Common.commonDependencies ++ Seq(
    ),
    Common.settings
  )

lazy val cms = (project in file("modules/cms"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(
    name := "app-cms",
    libraryDependencies ++= Common.commonDependencies,
    Common.settings
  )
  .dependsOn(core % "test->test;compile->compile")
  .aggregate(core)

lazy val api = (project in file("modules/api"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(
    name := "app-api",
    libraryDependencies ++= Common.commonDependencies,
    Common.settings
  )
  .dependsOn(core % "test->test;compile->compile")
  .aggregate(core)

lazy val reporting = (project in file("modules/reporting"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(
    name := "app-reporting",
    libraryDependencies ++= Common.commonDependencies,
    Common.settings
  )
  .dependsOn(core % "test->test;compile->compile")
  .aggregate(core)

lazy val backend = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(
    name := "app-backend",
    libraryDependencies ++= Common.commonDependencies
  )
  .dependsOn(
    core % "test->test;compile->compile",
    cms,
    api,
    reporting
  )
  .aggregate(cms, api, reporting)
```

I can't add an implicit Json format for My model User in the core module.

For the backend app, I can import w/o issues, is there something I'm missing here in the submodule part?

Thanks,

Comment: The issue was IntelliJ was messed up since I didn't follow the proper sbt layout, I had to manually setup each module in the Project Structure and its dependencies, then on the sbt right sidebar, I refreshed and it built the whole thing properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check if you are actually importing the `play-json` library because in Play 2.6 it is a standalone library:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % playVersion
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I thought about it as well, bu the Plugin PlayScala should be importing it, since I can access it at the top level project.