# Does Play subprojects need each an ApplicationLoader with Macwire?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, macwire

Given the following set of sub-projects:
[Play subproject can't import Play-json classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167005/play-subproject-cant-import-play-json-classes)

Should each Project need to have an independent ApplicationLoader?
For example for the `api` module, should I create and ApiApplicationLoader and for the parent project, should I also create a BackendApplicationLoader.

Take in consideration that the parent project is useful for Dev purposes, but when deploying each Module Api, Reporting and CMS might get deployed in different servers.
However, Core module should be shared, does that mean in that case.
CoreApplicationLoader is not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the setup of [guardian/frontend](https://github.com/guardian/frontend) where they have

- multiple application sub-projects (`article`, `discussion`, `sport`, `identity`, etc.)
- each application sub-project is deployed to a separate server
- each application sub-project has a separate application loader (`AppLoader`)
- shared common subproject which acts as a library and is not deployed (`common`)
- application sub-project for local development purposes which is not deployed (`dev-build`)
- wiring via MacWire

Comment: That link is what I needed, essential learning resource, I wish Play docs could point to relevant sample codes that were closer to real apps